# Add an Eclipse 4.4 Perspective in existing Eclipse 3 Application

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-luna

I have an existing Eclipse 3 RCP application (the compatibility layer is already added to the existing application) in which I would like to add a perspective (of course containing parts, toolbars, menus..) developed with Eclipse 4.4 (Luna).

1) Is this possible ?

2) If, yes could you please give me more information on how to do that and perhaps links containing more informations ?

UPDATE : So I finally manage it to make it work so for those of you who had the same questions here are the answers. So yes it is possible to mix Eclipse 3 and Eclipse 4(some complications but you can manage it :) ) for more information on how I did you can go to the link I left in a comment down below. Hope this going to be helpfull :)

Answer (score 0):

You can likely do something close. You could implement the 'createInitialPerspective' method of the your IPerspectiveFactory to downCast the given IPageLayout to its underlying class "ModeledPageLayout". This will give you access to the new MPerspective's model (as well as the useful utility methods). Then you're off to the races and can set the model for your perspective up as you desire (as long as the result can be rendered).

Comment: Thank you Eric for your anwser but I tried another solution and it worked perfectly the only trouble that I have now is to add the perspective to the perspective switcher. I posted the Link for the solution I have tried in a comment down below.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something that Alexander adviced me to do and it worked perfectly :) The only issue that I have now, is how to add the perspective added to the perspective switcher. (The method I followed enabled me to add the perspective but when I run the application it is displayed in the tool bar and I don't want it to be like that I want it to be only present in the perspective switcher). Anyway here's the link for the solution I tried. Hope this gona be help full.

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1690630/#msg_1690630